# How to escape Athena INSERT INTO error if string contains single quote and comma?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, presto

I have to INSERT a record into Athena, I have used below INSERT INTO query but I am getting error because of the column title which contains single quote and a comma after 35 in the string.

```
insert into database.product (title,description) 
values (
'Waxpol Vinyl & Leather Polish (35', Ltr.)',
'Restores with an extremely High & Durable Shine & Gloss.'
)
```

Error:

[image]
FYI: The table is a parquet format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape single quote in `'Waxpol Vinyl & Leather Polish (35', Ltr.)'` otherwise it becomes `'Waxpol Vinyl & Leather Polish (35'` string followed by some invalid SQL. You can do it by using extra single quote:

```sql
insert into database.product (title,description) 
values (
'Waxpol Vinyl & Leather Polish (35'', Ltr.)',
'Restores with an extremely High & Durable Shine & Gloss.'
)
```